# Setting Printer permissions using python on windows doesn't work

Tags: python, acl

I am new to Python. I am trying to set Access permissions for all users in this code. The script runs but the access rights are not reflected or set. I am trying to set the following permissions for all printers for these users:

- Everyone - Print
- CREATOR OWNER - Manage Documents
- Any Administrator - Print, Manage Printers, Manage Documents
- Administrators - Print, Manage Printers, Manage Documents
- All other users - Print

Here is the code:

```
import win32com.client
import win32security
from win32security import DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, TRUSTEE_IS_NAME, TRUSTEE_IS_USER
import win32net
import win32security
import win32netcon
import win32file

ManagePrinters = 983052
ManageDocuments = 983088
Print = 131080
ReadPermissions = 131072
GenericAll = 268435456
GenericExecute =  536870912

administrators = []

compliant = True

for x in win32net.NetLocalGroupGetMembers("localhost","Administrators", 2)[0]:
username =  x["domainandname"]
usersid = str(win32security.LookupAccountName("",username)[0])[6:]
administrators.append(usersid)

info=win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION

strComputer = "."
objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\cimv2")
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer")
for objItem in colItems:
secDes = win32security.GetNamedSecurityInfo(objItem.DeviceID, win32security.SE_PRINTER, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
dacl = secDes.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
for count in range(dacl.GetAceCount()):
    ace = dacl.GetAce(count)
    accessMask = ace[1]
    sidArr = str(ace[2]).split(":",1)
    sid = sidArr[1]
    newAcl = win32security.ACL(128)


    if "S-1-3-0" in sid:
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(Print, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(ManageDocuments, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(GenericAll, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(ReadPermissions, ace[2])
    elif "S-1-1-0" in sid:
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(Print, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(GenericExecute, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(ReadPermissions, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(ManageDocuments, ace[2])
    elif "S-1-5-32-544" in sid:
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(Print, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(ManageDocuments, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(GenericAll, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(ReadPermissions, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(ManagePrinters, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(GenericExecute, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(ReadPermissions, ace[2])
    elif sid in administrators:
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(Print, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(ManageDocuments, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(GenericAll, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(ReadPermissions, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(ManagePrinters, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(GenericExecute, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(ReadPermissions, ace[2])
    else:
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(Print, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(GenericExecute, ace[2])
        newAcl.AddAccessAllowedAce(ReadPermissions, ace[2])

    secDes.SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(1, newAcl, 0)

print "done"
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're actually applying the modified DACL
to the printer.  Try using win32security.SetNamedSecurityInfo.